# CNN trained model not saved properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, backend

I am a novice in using tensorflow and I built a CNN which is trained and tested both with 80-85% accuracy. I tried to save my trained model using `model.save('example.h5')`, and download the file using `files.download('example.h5')`

Afterwards I tried to load it to my flask back-end using `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('example.h5')`.

When I tried using it with random images, it's like the model has never been trained before. Any solutions? thank you

Answer (score 0):

A common reason to this might be that you are normalizing your data on training but not before predicting. Make sure you normalize the input data before you run predictions, if you have trained on normalized data.